# javascript function for different browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I am trying to work on some action based on the browser in rails. So I have this in my index.rhtml

```
<div class="function_tes">
        <function whichBrwsr() 
        {
        var agt=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        if (agt.indexOf("msie") != -1) return 'IE';
                  if (agt.indexOf("firefox") != -1) return 'Firefox';
        }>

</div>
```

However, I do not see any result of "IE" nor "firefox" when I open index in those browser. Do I need to call whichBrwsr() somewhere in index.rhtml or?

Thank you for any guidance

Comment: This is a pure Javascript question, it has nothing to do with rails, so I removed your rails tag.

Comment: yes aggree. This script should also work in rails, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
<div id="myDiv" class="function_tes">
</div>
<script type="text\javascript">
        function whichBrwsr() 
        {
        var agt=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        if (agt.indexOf("msie") != -1) return 'IE';
                  if (agt.indexOf("firefox") != -1) return 'Firefox';
        }
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHtml = whichBrwsr();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but it did not work. It print all words of the function on index instead.. (and not IE nor firefox)

Comment: @heike...Above should work.  Not I added an ID to your div so I could set the innerHTML via javascript.

Comment: Thank you for the logic. But somehow in my browser, I don't see anything. But no error either